# Google Sheet - QUERY SELECT does not handle apostrophe in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: google-sheets

I have this Google Sheet report.

The problem is when my client name has an apostrophe, it breaks the formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(Projects!$1:$2018, "select sum(G) where A='"&A2&"'"),2), 0)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16UOU5iMwieHjVmV81TdK3_emxyj-wFqXa8u5Nia7Wkg/edit#gid=1016414243

Do you know how I can change this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with triple double quotes to escape those single quotes you have:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(Projects!$1:$2018, "select sum(G) where A="""&A2&""""),2), 0)
```

[image]

You can also use SUMIF, and don't worry about how the values are written:

```
=SUMIF(Projects!A:A,A2,Projects!G:G)
```

[image]